# Spring JPA getting new Transaction for Every method call and transaction not work properly

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions, transactional

> i am using Spring Data JPA i am saving multiple objects from one method  and when something happens after saving the first object then first saved object should be rollback but this is not happening when I see the logs I found that getting new transaction for every method call and committing it below is my service layer method in which I created "nullPointerException" after the first object persisted

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void testTransaction(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap) throws Exception {
        try {
            VendorType  vendorType  = (VendorType) hashMap.get("vendorType");
            RenewalType renewalType = (RenewalType) hashMap.get("renewalType");

            vendorTypeService.registerNewVendorType(vendorType);
            Vehicle vehicle = null;
            vehicle.getCompany_Id();
            renewalTypeService.registerNewRenewalType(renewalType);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("inside method exception "+e);
        }
    }
```

below is registerVendor Method which is defined in the different service method

```
 @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public VendorType registerNewVendorType(final VendorType accountDto) throws Exception {

    return VendorTyperepository.save(accountDto);
}
```

this is my config file PersistenceJPAConfig.java

```
 @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "org.fleetopgroup.persistence" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.fleetopgroup.persistence.dao")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public PersistenceJPAConfig() {
        super();
    }

    //

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.fleetopgroup.persistence.model" });
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    final Properties additionalProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

Below is Log Trace : 

web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,566 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Initializing transaction synchronization
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,566 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.fleetopgroup.persistence.service.VehicleService.testTransaction]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,567 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'org.fleetopgroup.persistence.service.VendorTypeService.registerNewVendorType' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,567 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@23976e80] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@45f6c4a9] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,567 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@30496576] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@6007487a] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,567 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.fleetopgroup.persistence.service.VendorTypeService.registerNewVendorType]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,567 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@5dbd844] for key [public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object)] to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,567 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@23976e80] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@45f6c4a9] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,567 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@30496576] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@6007487a] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,567 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,574 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@23976e80] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@45f6c4a9] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
Hibernate: insert into vendortype (companyId, createdBy, createdOn, lastModifiedBy, lastModifiedOn, markForDelete, vendor_TypeName) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,625 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,625 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Removed value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@5dbd844] for key [public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object)] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,625 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.fleetopgroup.persistence.service.VendorTypeService.registerNewVendorType]
inside method exception java.lang.NullPointerException
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,625 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.fleetopgroup.persistence.service.VehicleService.testTransaction]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,626 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Clearing transaction synchronization
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,627 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@23976e80] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@45f6c4a9] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
web - 2018-03-22 10:53:15,627 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@30496576] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@6007487a] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
```

MyController.java

```
@Controller
public class MyControllerextends MainActivity {

   @Autowired
    private IVehicleService vehicleService;

*@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test() throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, Object>         model           = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            CustomUserDetails   userDetails =       (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            VendorType  vendorType  = new  VendorType();
            vendorType.setVendor_TypeName("TEST");
            vendorType.setCreatedBy("manish");
            vendorType.setCreatedOn(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            vendorType.setCompanyId(userDetails.getCompany_id());

            RenewalType renewalType = new RenewalType();
            renewalType.setRenewal_Type("test type");
            renewalType.setCreatedBy("manish");
            renewalType.setCreatedOn(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            renewalType.setCompanyId(userDetails.getCompany_id());
            model.put("renewalType", renewalType);
            model.put("vendorType", vendorType);
            vehicleService.testTransaction(model);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/vehicle/1/1.in?danger=true");
}
```

IVehicleService.java

```
public interface IVehicleService {
   public void testTransaction(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap) throws Exception;
}
```

VehicleService.java

```
 @Service("VehicleService")
    @Transactional (readOnly = true)
    public class VehicleService implements IVehicleService {

@Autowired
    private IVendorTypeService      vendorTypeService;

       @Override
        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false)
        public void testTransaction(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap) throws Exception {
                try {
                    RenewalType renewalType =   (RenewalType) hashMap.get("renewalType");
                    VendorType  vendorType =    (VendorType) hashMap.get("vendorType");

                    vendorTypeService.registerNewVendorType(vendorType);
                    Vehicle vehicle = null;
                    vehicle.getCompany_Id();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
        }
    }
```

IVendorTypeService.java

```
public interface IVendorTypeService {
  public VendorType registerNewVendorType(VendorType GET_DocType) throws Exception;
}
```

VendorTypeService.java

```
@Service
public class VendorTypeService implements IVendorTypeService {
    @Autowired
    private VendorTypeRepository VendorTyperepository;


    // API

    @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
    public VendorType registerNewVendorType(final VendorType accountDto) throws Exception {

        return VendorTyperepository.save(accountDto);
    }
}
```

VendorTypeRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface VendorTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<VendorType, Long> {

}
```

Comment: You don't re-throw the NullPointerException. You just catch it.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i did not understand what you want to say?

Comment: } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("inside method exception "+e);
        } you catch the exception so the transaction will never rollback

Comment: @SimonMartinelli after doing it also it is not rollbacking because you can se log trace that after saving first object only it is commiting and creating diff transaction for all method call

Comment: Hibernate: insert into vendortype (companyId, createdBy, createdOn, lastModifiedBy, lastModifiedOn, markForDelete, vendor_TypeName) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
web - 2018-03-22 13:53:36,142 [http-nio-8080-exec-144] TRACE o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]

Comment: is the test class in the same package as defined in bean config - `org.fleetopgroup.persistence` ? Cause spring manages transactions differently for test classes refer - [testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/testing.html#testing-tx)

Comment: can you please add the code of the service definition, the repository and the test class (how these classes are annotated)

Comment: @osamayaccoub see the edits i have added what you want

Comment: @AmitNaik config and test classes are in diff packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with MySql Database storage Engine in hibernate configuration dialect property was MySQLDialect after changing to MySQLInnoDBDialect And alter table engine to InnoDB  now it is working fine

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```